# npm link "The file is marked as an executable but could not be run by the operating system."

Tags: node.js, npm, symlink, package.json

So I made a cli with `package.json` that specifies a bin file.

I `npm link`'d it. Then I created a new folder on my desktop and `npm link foocli` which installed it fine to that directory's `node_modules` folder.

Then I try to run the cli from that dir and it throws:

`The file '/usr/local/bin/foocli' is marked as an executable but could not be run by the operating system.`

Any idea what's causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Do you have `#!/usr/bin/env node` as the first line of your executable file?

Comment: Ah! That was it. I'm an idiot. I had it in there, but went to redo the entire file and erased everything and forgot to add it back. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/env node` is needed at the top of the file that is being executed so the shell knows how to execute the file.